# Azure AKS Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable dial tcp no such host 443

Tags: azure, terraform, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks

I'm trying to run helm command from my terraform configuration. But i'm getting kubernetes cluster unreachable error. My cluster is private and i don't want to change it. How can i access it?

> Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get
> "https://aksdns-8f2967.c8e977-d63e-461f-a4b6-c356d1.privatelink.westeurope.azmk8s.io:443/version":
> dial tcp: lookup
> aksdns-8f67.c8e95477-d63e-461f-a4b6-c33b2d6d1.privatelink.westeurope.azmk8s.io
> on 192.168.1.1:53: no such host

```
resource "helm_release" "ingress-nginx" {
  name             = "ingress-nginx"
  namespace        = "ingress-nginx"
  create_namespace = true
  repository       = "https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx"
  chart            = "ingress-nginx"

  values = [
    file("ingress-nginx-values.yaml")
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to run your Terraform scripts from a machine (like a build agent) that is connected via VNet connection to that private cluster. That is the whole point of private clusters: The control plane is only accessible to machines with direct line-of-sight, not over the internet.